# Do I require to set cleanSession parameter (persistent session) for MQTT Client which only publishes?

Tags: mqtt

A MQTT client is not subscribing, but only publishing messages to topics with QOS 1, does it need to have persistent session?

As far as I understand only subscribing clients needs to set cleanSession parameter as per their QOS requirements.Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no need to maintain a persistent session for a client that is only publishing messages.

Comment: Going through this link before saw your reply. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029030_.htm                                                                [Quote]"For QoS=1 and QoS=2, using cleanSession=true might result in losing a publication." [Unquote]                                                         So does this mean for a QoS1 Publisher, I need to set cleanSession param as false, in order to not loose a publication?

Comment: I suppose in theory, if a message was half ready through the QOS 1/2 handshake when the connection dropped you could carry on with a persistent session when the connection read restored